# Container builder dockerfile with gcloud commands

Tags: google-container-registry, google-container-builder

I have a container builder step

```
steps:
- id: dockerbuild
  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - -c
  - |
    docker build . -t test 
images: ['gcr.io/project/test']
```

The Dockerfile used to create this test image has gsutil specific commands like

```
FROM gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
RUN gsutil ls
```

When I submit a docker build to container builder service using

```
gcloud container builds submit --config cloudbuild.yml
```

I see the following error

```
You are attempting to perform an operation that requires a project id, with none configured. Please re-run gsutil config and make sure to follow the instructions for finding and entering your default project id.
The command '/bin/sh -c gsutil ls' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: exit status 1
```

My question is, how do we use gcloud/gsutil commands inside the DockerFile so that I can run inside a docker build step ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [not able to perform gcloud init inside dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428287/not-able-to-perform-gcloud-init-inside-dockerfile)

Comment: no I am trying to refer to a different use-case.

Comment: I have a container builder docker step. Inside the docker file I would like to run gcloud/gsutil commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To invoke "gcloud commands." using the tool builder, you need [Container Builder service account](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions), because it executes your builds on your behalf.

Here in this [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/gcloud/cloudbuild.yaml) there is an example for cloud-builders using the gcloud command:

Note : you have to specify $PROJECT_ID it's mandatory for your builder to work.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, your `Dockerfile` either needs to start from a base image that has the cloud SDK installed already (like `FROM gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud`) or you would need to install it. Here's a `Dockerfile` that installs it: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/gcloud/Dockerfile.slim

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried to do the same but issuing a gcloud/gsutil command inside a container builder step's dockerfile throws a error that  I do not have enough permissions